# Aligning controls using the Visual Studio 2010 Resource Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resource-editor

I am creating a calculator using MFC dialog based and I want to align the buttons but in order to determine where to place the next button there's no guide like a line.When I read I found that snap lines help with it.Therefore using **tools->Options->Windows forms designer->general** I set LayoutMode to SnapLines,Show Grid to False , Snap To Grid to False.But still I can't see lines that help me to arrange buttons in the dialog form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guides aren't created automatically for you, you have to set them yourself. This is done by clicking inside the rulers to the top (for vertical guides) or to the left (for horizontal guides) of the dialog:[image]

Once set you can move guides around as desired by clicking on the arrow inside the ruler area. To remove a guide, simply drag an arrow outside the ruler area.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out how to remove a guide